# Mapping FTP and SFTP as Network Drive in Windows programmatically (Network redirector)

Tags: c#, ftp, sftp, network-drive

I have been assigned an internal task that i need to write a Windows App in C# that, when user input their username and password, Windows magically map the FTP or SFTP folder as a network drive.

I have go through some research and seems "Network Redirector" is the answer of my question.

I am not very familiar with windows thingies, can anyone tell me if this is the right direction? Or you have better clues?

Thanks.

Comment: This is an enormous task. You're right on the spot with "magically". :)

Comment: i just quoted my boss' word, mate :) if the task is enormous i wish to know why and tell my boss structurally how long it would takes to accomplish. :D

Comment: @Bill Kary if you want to write everything from scratch - about 2 years for one person. If you use third-party libraries, then the task is shrunk to one month of intensive work.

Comment: Hi Eugene, when you say third-party libraries, what's the difference in development time between using Callback File System and Dokan Library? can u specify? thanks.

Comment: Step back and ask yourself, "Is this the best solution to this problem?"  What if, instead, you had a shared network folder that was constantly and automatically syncronized to a folder or folders on a remote FTP site.  Then the user would just connect to a normal network drive and use it just like any other network drive and file changes would be automatically replicated to the FTP site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a virtual file system backed by FTP or SFTP server. This can be done using our [Callback File System](http://www.eldos.com/cbfs/) library (FTP or SFTP part can be accomplished using our other product, SecureBlackbox). There also exists Dokan library, which attempts to mimic FUSE on Windows and create a virtual disk.

If you can go with an end-user solution, we implemented **free** [SFTP Net Drive](http://www.eldos.com/sftp-net-drive/) application that uses our Callback File System and maps SFTP server to a virtual drive.

Answer (score 1):

[WebDrive](http://www.southrivertech.com/products/webdrive/winindex.html) maps a network drive to FTP and SFTP servers and supports FTP over SSL. There is an API that lets you programmatically map and unmap the drive.  Supported commands are detailed in the WebDrive [help file](http://www.southrivertech.com/support/webdrive/v9/webdrive.htm).  Go to the "Advanced Topics" section and look at the topics on "Automating Connections" as well as the "Scripting and Batch Files" section.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a free tool called [FtpUse](http://www.ferrobackup.com/ftpuse/) for mapping FTP directories to a drive letter via command line. It does not support SFTP. Maybe this is simplest approach to mount a FTP resource programmatically.

Comment: [Boomkop3](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6523393/boomkop3) suggested: “However using this tool you can't create new files and the filesystem has to be remounted to refresh a folder's contents.” Is this correct?